# Why do I get error 3073 in VBA when using "TransferSpreadsheet acImport" but not when using "TransferSpreadsheet acLink"

Tags: sql, vba, database, ms-access

I just want to import a number of Excel sheets into MS Access to combine data from several months (each in one .xlsx file). Got it to work as long as I link the .xlsx files using

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, tableName, fileName, True, "A4:L23"
```

but not when using acImport option

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, tableName, fileName, True, "A4:L23"
```

I get an 'error 3073 - Operation must use an updatable query' when I change the option from Link to Import.

As I want to add a column containing the month and year for which the data applies, I need to be able to add a variable which i cannot do using linked tables.

Thanks for your suggestions or an explanation of what I am doing wrong.

KR,
Martin

Comment: What's the full error message?

Comment: Dear Andre, thank you for asking! the full error Message is: Operation must use an updatable query.

Comment: Make sure that `tableName` doesn't exist in your database before importing.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml`:

[AcSpreadSheetType enumeration (Access)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.acspreadsheettype?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361)

Comment: Dear Gustav, I tried your suggestion- Thank you for that! Unfortunately, I still get the same error (Operation must use an updatable query).

Comment: Code works fine here, so something else is going on, as no query is involved. Double-check your table and query names.

Answer (score 0):

Andre and Gustav,

thanks to both of you for your help!! Really appreciate it!

I thought I should test the code in a new Access DB and the code does work there. The issue seems to be caused when you switch between linking and importing in the same database.
In the new DB I can switch between importing and linking (acLink/acimport in the DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet statement), but imported or linked tables must be deleted in Access BEFORE running the vba code. Maybe that is obvious to most of you, but was not to me :-)